# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api

Tags: python-3.x, windows, jupyter-notebook

I am using embedded python 3.7.4
Getting the folliwng error when trying to create new file in jupyter notebook
*File "D:\Users\sgangop7\python3.7.4\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 387, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'*

Solutions Tried:

1. fresh install of jupyter notebook
2. pip install pypiwin32
3. pip install pywin32
4. Running the pywin32_postinstall.py
5. Added 'D:\Users\sgangop7\python3.7.4\Lib\site-packages' in the PATH variable of environment variable
6. Copied 'win32api.pyd' to 'D:\Users\sgangop7\python3.7.4\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib'
7. I cannot find any other solution for how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

On your jupyter notebook, you can try these commands :

```
import sys
sys.path
```

You will see a list of paths which Python is using to find packages. If your path "D:\Users\sgangop7\python3.7.4\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib" isn't in the list, you may need to add it. You can do it like this :

```
sys.path.insert("D:\Users\sgangop7\python3.7.4\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib")
```

Good luck !